# How to do XML Encryption 128 bit in WPF

Tags: wpf, xml, encryption

I want to encrypt a XML file in Wpf to 128 bit. Can anyone tell me how it is done through code in C#? And what is it exactly 128 bit encryption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

128 bit is the size of key in encryption algorithm. Longer the key; the harder it is to crack the encryption. In .NET you can use AES or Rijndael for 128 bit encryption.
See [Keep Your Data Secure with the New Advanced Encryption Standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164055.aspx)